# For loop with unix find

Tags: command-line, scripts, find

Trying to do a mass convert from M4A to OGG in a large music collection, I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `find /home/family/Music -name *.m4a -print0`
   #do ffmpeg -i "$i" -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 "$i.ogg";
   do echo $i
done
```

All of the files will have spaces in their names, the output for the above shows a single file like this:

```
/home/family/Music/The
Kooks/Inside
In
_
Inside
Out/06
You
Don't
Love
Me.m4a
```

Every space marks a new line, I thought `-print0` would fix this?

Comment: cd /home/family/Music , for in *.m4a; do ffmpeg .... ; done

Comment: `$ for i in *.m4a; do echo $i; done`
`*.m4a`
The files are in subfolders, don't think this works

Comment: You should probably include such information in your question.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/409818/how-do-i-parse-the-output-of-the-find-command-when-filenames-have-spaces-in-them

Comment: @will Should probably be mentioned on this site to. Do not [cross-post questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158679/find-and-for-loop). Again SO has [a terrific answer on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724)

Answer (score 15):

That's one of the reasons why you *never* use a `for` loop to iterate over a command whose output can contain spaces. Especially if that output is a list of file names that can contain *anything* except `/` and `\0`.  You have fallen into [bash pitfall number 1](http://bash.cumulonim.biz/BashPitfalls.html#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Always use `while` instead. To make sure it works with all file names, including those with spaces, newlines, tabs, backslashes or any other strange characters, use this:

```
find /home/family/Music -name '*.m4a' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
     ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 "${file%.m4a}.ogg";
done
```

#### Explanation

- Note that I quoted `*.mp4a` which ensures that bash will not expand it before passing it to `find`. This is important for the cases where you have files that match that glob in your current directory.
- The `-print0`, as you probably know, causes `find` to separate its results with `\0` instead of newlines.
- `IFS=` : This sets the input field character to nothing, ensuring that no word splitting will take place.
- `while read -r -d '' file`: This will iterate over the results, saving each as `$file`, just like `for file in $(command)`. The options are (from `help read`):

  ```
   -r     do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
   -d delim   continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
      than newline
  ```

  Setting the delimiter to the empty string (`-d ''`) makes `read` play nice with find's `-print0`.
- `"${file%.mp3}.ogg";` :  This is simply to remove the `.m4a` suffix and replace it with `.ogg` so you get `foo.ogg` instead of `foo.m4a.ogg`.

The rest is the same as you had attempted so I'm guessing you understand it.

Comment: great answer , just wondering why there are 2 times do - am I missing something or is it a bug ?! ...

Comment: @YordanGeorgiev a bug, I had copied the command from the OP and it included a `do`. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xargs.1.html) with `-0` option, or use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/find.1.html)'s  own `exec` option:

```
find /home/family/Music -name '*.m4a' -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 "{}.ogg" \;
# or:
find /home/family/Music -name '*.m4a' -print0 | xargs -0 -i ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 {}.ogg
```

Note that in both cases (and in your original command), `x.m4a` will be converted to `x.m4a.ogg`.

Comment: `find /home/family/Music -name '*.m4a' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 "${0%.m4a}.ogg"' '{}' \;` will fix the filename issue.

Answer (score 2):

This may be solution of what you want

```
#!/bin/bash    
find  /home/family/Music -type f -name '*.m4a' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; 
  do
   #do ffmpeg -i "$i" -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 -vn -ac 2 "$i.ogg"; 
   echo $i
done
```